# Autocorrection between the position of two images

Tags: image, matlab

I have two images and have to divide that image. Due to manual error the area in the image is not as same. How can i correct it automatically using matlab so as to perform divison pixel by pixel accurately?

Comment: Do you simply mean `I1 ./ I2`?

Comment: Please describe a bit more accurately what you have and what you want.

Comment: Do you mean you have to transform one image (shift, rotate, etc) to match the other? If so, the answer will depend on what sort of transform you need. If you have the Image Processing Toolbox, look up the Image Registration demos.

Comment: maybe just use `imresize`?

Comment: The main question I believe - what happened to the images that now they are not the same size? if they were resided differently then the answer bellow by Roney Michael is the one to go, if it was cut somehow then there are other methods to apply.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried to ovelay the images on each other but because of the differences in image they dont overlay properly as to luk alike. I used image registeration using control points, here i found that each time  wen i change my set of images, control points have to be changed. I want to overlay the images automatically with different sets of images. Can anyone help

Answer (score 0):

Once you've read both image files into the variables, say `A` and `B`, assuming `A` contains the image of the size you actually want and `B` contains the image of the size you want to change, you could use:

```
[numrows numcols] = size(A);
A = imresize(A, [numrows numcols]);
```